# Responsive table layout suggestion

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is there an easy way to convert a table based layout on a website to a responsive design without setting the width and height of each row and cell in my code

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed number of columns than i have one solution for you, 
sample code and screen below.

**Desktop Screen**
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Mobile Screen (width < 760)**

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

***Html Code for Above screen***

```
<table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>First Name</th>
               <th>Last Name</th>
               <th>Phone Number</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>Anil</td>
               <td>Kumar</td>
               <td>+91 9022669735</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Sunil</td>
               <td>Kumar</td>
               <td>+91 9405889360</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
```

***Styles***

```
table { 
             width: 100%; 
             border-collapse: collapse; 
         }
         tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
             background: #eee; 
         }
         th { 
             background: #333; 
             color: white; 
             font-weight: bold; 
         }
         td, th { 
             padding: 6px; 
             border: 1px solid #ccc; 
             text-align: left; 
         }
         @media only screen and (max-width: 760px),
         (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

             /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
             table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
                 display: block; 
             }
             /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
             thead tr { 
                 position: absolute;
                 top: -9999px;
                 left: -9999px;
             }
             tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

             td { 
                 /* Behave  like a "row" */
                 border: none;
                 border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
                 position: relative;
                 padding-left: 50%; 
             }

             td:before { 
                 /* Now like a table header */
                 position: absolute;
                 /* Top/left values mimic padding */
                 top: 6px;
                 left: 6px;
                 width: 45%; 
                 padding-right: 10px; 
                 white-space: nowrap;
             }
             td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
             td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
             td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Phone Number"; }
         }
```

**HOPE THIS WILL HELP YOU**

Comment: It isn't one table that needs styling, it's an entire website with a layout that uses tables to get a great layout

Comment: this could be tedious task for anyone, in case of table layout. or you can check some options from http://exisweb.net/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns